# AlpacaJS - How to access file uploaded in File Field in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, alpacajs

I have a form with the following super basic file field:

Schema-

```
"file_upload": {
        "type": "string"
 }
```

Options-

```
    "file_upload": {
            "type": "file"
    }
```

I want to access the file uploaded somehow, but particularly through Handlebars.js.

A regular field, say `"file_checkbox"` can be rendered using `{{file_checkbox}}` in handlebars but I can **not** figure out how to access the file.

Using basic javascript (`document.getElementById('fieldId').files`), I can see that the file has uploaded as anticipated.

But, trying to get the value of the Alpaca Form (`$.alpaca($("#formDiv")).getValue()`) yields the data from the regular fields (i.e. `file_checkbox`) and **nothing** from the file field.

When I submit the alpaca form all of the other data is properly saved, but again nothing from the file field (not even the name of the field with an empty/nil value)!

I've spent many hours searching and haven't found anything on the Alpaca website, Github Issues, or stack overflow! This is my first question so please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's normal with Alpaca, there will be no data for your file input set in your form data object, you should use the function `selectionHandler` to set the file(s) selected (*you can use either File or Base64 data*) to your form data like this :

```
"file-upload": {
    "type": "file",
    "selectionHandler": function(files, data) {
       // files for multiple or use files[0] to get only one file
       // and if you want to use base64 data you could use data 
       this.data = files;
    }
 }
```

And here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/pv4oxrLd/) for that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment vert3x! I also had seen your question regarding the FILE field and this solution. However, adding the JS inside my Options JSON crashes the form and renders me unable to save. Must be the way I'm handling the JSON... The other issue is how to access the file using Handlebars but if you're saying that I can't save the file with the form then it's probably not possible and I'll have to stick to using the Upload field unfortunately. Thanks again!

Comment: Were you adding the file into the JSON? That would have been one really big JSON.